# "Conley index " as a tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Is there a tag which can be related to methods on Conley index theory?I could not find a tag with this title.

Comment: "Conley index" (with quotation marks) yields 14 references in Mathoverflow. Since you get this list by a straightforward search, the tag would be of little benefit. In general tags of broader audience are more useful.

Comment: Are you also asking what tag to apply to questions about Conley index theory, or only whether a tag [conley-index-theory] exists (or should exist)?